# Can't add particular values to the database

Tags: sql, database, netbeans, token

So I'm currently having a problem where I can't seem to add values to my sql-database. I'm constantly getting sql error 104. Saying that some tokens are unknown.

```
try{
```

//The part below gets the employee-ID and the names of the skill I want to add to him/her.

```
    String valdAnstalld = jComboBoxUppKompVal.getSelectedItem().toString();
    String nyKomp = jComboBoxUppKID.getSelectedItem().toString();
    String nyP = jComboBoxUppPF.getSelectedItem().toString();
    String nyNiva = jComboBoxUppNiva.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

//This part takes the name of the skill, and gets its ID-number.

```
    String KompID = "select kid from kompetensdoman where benamning = '" + nyKomp + "'";
    String PlattID = "select pid from plattform where benamning = '" + nyP + "'";
```

//And finally this part is supposed to insert the ID-numbers into the "has_competance" table.

```
    String sqlUppKomp = "insert into har_kompetens VALUES " + "(" + valdAnstalld + ", '" 
            + KompID + "', '" + PlattID + "', '" + nyNiva + "' where aid = '" + valdAnstalld + "')";

    idb.insert(sqlUppKomp);

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Tillagd!");
}
 catch(Exception e)
{
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
}
 uppdateraKomp();
```

Comment: `VALUES " + "(" + valdAnstalld + ", '"`
Missing a quote in `+ "(" +` .

Comment: Thanks, didn't notice that, didn't seem to solve the problem though. Tried both with and without quotes around valdAnstalld now.

Comment: can you post the exact error message

Comment: Sure, 
SQL error code = -104
Token unknown line 1 column 91
C
(The last part, C, is the first letter/word of the skill we're trying to add.)

Comment: I didnt notice earlier but there is another `'` missing after `valdAnstalld` @ `+ ", '"`

Comment: Yes, must have been left that way after using auto-increment in some earlier stage of the coding. As I said, we tried both with and without the quotes this time. All of the values being inserted are numbers, converted to strings, if that makes any difference.